# Encrypted file name on download and not in expected language i.e. Arabic

Tags: java, arabic, urlencode, content-disposition, response-headers

I am trying to download file whose name is in Arabic language. Content of file is in arabic but name gets encrypted on download.

```
responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition",
                                "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"; filename*=utf-8''" + URLEncoder
                                        .encode(fileName, "UTF-8"));
```

fileName at this point is in Arabic language but on browser's response Header fileName gets changed to something else like **E1-(E1-(.txt**

Http Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 10
Content-encoding: gzip
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="E1-(E1-(.txt.txt"; 
filename*=utf-8''%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7.txt
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
X-Backend: supra-prod-pdx-ff4d74bff-7srf7
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
X-Slack-Meta: proxy
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us the concrete value of Content-Disposition.

Comment: @JulianReschke Updated the question.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but does your `filename*` value need to be quoted? And/or, does `utf-8` need to be capitalized? `filename*="UTF-8''%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7.txt"`

Comment: @yshavit , here is the Response Header of Slack application where it is working fine: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="__________.txt"; filename*=utf-8''%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7.txt
Content-Type: application/force-download`

Answer (score 0):

OKay, so at the UI side one can achieve this.

In the Response Header, **fileName*** provide the encoded value and at the UI end decode the value using following JS method: 
remove **utf8''** from the string, so you'll get the actual file name.

```
window.decodeURIComponent(t.substring(t.lastIndexOf('\'')+1,t.length));
```